Aplicación compilada con pyinstall no se ejecuta
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con interfaz grafica echo con python 3 pero al crear un ejecutable con pyinstall se crea el archivo .exe y las dependencias compiladas pera al intentar ejecutar el ejecutable se abre la consola le toma unos segundos y se sierra sin lanzar nada, el comando usado es: ruta del archivo .py maestro -i ruta del icono --collect-submodules imports
Los módulos que importo son numpy, multiprosses, tkinter, colorsys, math, primer3, Bio.SeqUtils, adicionalmente importo barios archivos .py que son bibliotecas personalizadas es decir archivos .py en el mismo directorio que el archivo maestro y que contiene funciones por cosas de orden (el proyecto es realmente grande con mas de 1500 líneas de código en total) el problema no esta en tkinter, ya probé compilar una interfaz grafica simple y funciona y mi primera lineal de código en el archivo maestro luego de importar todo es multiprocessing.freeze_support()
el único mensaje que aparece en terminal tanto cuando se lanza con el ejecutable como con el cmd es: longjump, inmediatamente después de esto la ventana se sierra al usar el ejecutable de forma nativa. Cuando uso -d imports en lugar de  --collect-submodules imports, puedo ver que se realizan las importaciones de las dependencias pero en ultima instancia salta el longjump. Creo que sobra decirlo pero el código funciona perfectamente desde el interprete de python.
Como informacion adicional mi computadora tiene un amd rayzen 5, una placa de video gtx 1650, el almacenamiento C: es un SSD de 160 Gb y la unidad D: es un HDD de 1 Tb, y tiene 12 Gb de ram en DDR5.
asta el momento e intentado, la opción de --onefile, testear si tkinter o multiprosses tenían la culpa, probar ejecutar como administrador, probar compilar desde una terminal de administrador. Asta el momento no e podido ni replicar el fallo ni compilar un ejecutable funcional del proyecto por lo que no tengo idea de que lo causa o mucho menos como repáralo

hecho, cierra, varios, hasta, he

actualización, probando todas la cosas que se me ocurrieron sin ninguna idea de que causaba el problema pude rastrear el error a el modulo primer3, el código necesario para replicar el problema es import primer3 as p print(p..calc_tm("AAACTACA") y compilar con pyinstaller
